# Adding an input text box to a slider to show the value

Tags: reactjs, input, slider, jsx

For React with JSX in the app.js file I'm trying to add a text box which reads out the value of a slider like here https://codesandbox.io/s/ywyjro?file=/demo.tsx but here is what I have tried. Also the range should be from -50 to 50 but I don't see 0 half way

```
<input type='range' min='-50' max='50' step='10'/>
<input type='text /><br></br>
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" step="10" value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}/>
      <p>{val}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-example-forked-4q7vcw?file=/src/index.js

You should store the slider value in a state, and then present it in a separate element. You should not use an `<input />` element to display the value if the display is not meant to have input functionality.